# A question on an answer on Math Overflow about the tangent bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-theory

I have a question on the accepted answer of this [Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41979/relationship-between-tangent-bundle-and-tangent-sheaf).

Let $K$ be a field and $X$ a $K$-scheme. Define the morphism of *schemes* $T=\operatorname{Spec}\operatorname{Sym}(\Omega_{X/K}) \to X$ as the tangent bundle of $X$ as suggested in the answer. As it is said there, this is not always locally trivial.

Further it is said (somehow) in the answer that $T(C)=\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Spec}(K)}(\operatorname{Spec}(C[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)),X)$ for a $K$-algebra $C$ which I don't understand. How can you insert $C$ into a scheme $T$? Should this be $$T(Z)=\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Spec}(K)}(\operatorname{Spec}(C[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)),X)$$ for an open and affine subscheme $Z=\operatorname{Spec}(C)$ of $X$ instead?

Is it (theorefore?) possible to understand the ''whole bundle'' $T$ as follows: There is the notion of a *hom-sheaf*
$$
V\mapsto \mathcal{H}om_{\operatorname{Spec}(K)}(\operatorname{Spec}(K[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2))|_V,X|_V)=:S(V)
$$
which is a functor $S:(Schemes/K)^{op}\to Sets$.

> Is this functor representable by the scheme $T$, i.e. is there an isomorphism
>   $$ \operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Spec}(K)}(-,T) \cong S(-)$$
>   of functors $(Schemes/K)^{op}\to Sets$?

Comment: If $X$ is a $K$-scheme and $C$ is any $K$-algebra, then $X(C)$ denotes $\textbf{Sch}_{/K} (\operatorname{Spec} C, X)$. This is standard notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, the answer is no, you do not need to assume that $Z = \operatorname{Spec}(C)$ is an open affine subscheme of $X.$ The notation $T(C)$ refers to the $C$-valued points of $X,$ where $C$ is, as mentioned, an *arbitrary* $K$-algebra. In other words, $T(C) = \operatorname{Hom}_K(\operatorname{Spec}(C),T),$ by definition.

Your confusion probably arises because the equality mentioned, $$T(C) = \operatorname{Hom}_K(\operatorname{Spec}(C[t]/t^2),X)$$ is actually a specification of *what we want the $C$-valued points of $T$ to be*, before actually knowing $T$ exists. That is, there should be, and is, an isomorphism of functors from $T(-)$ to $\operatorname{Hom}_K(\operatorname{Spec}(-\times_K K[t]/t^2),X).$ This is what it means for the functor on the right hand side to be *representable* (by the scheme $T$).

Actually, we have to be a bit more careful, since the domain of our functors here is actually only affine schemes. To fully prove representability, we need to show that we can glue the local data. There is a nice description of the construction of the tangent bundles and jet schemes (the higher order version) in some papers of [Mustata-Ein](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612862) and [Ishii](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3327) on the arXiv.

Comment: Dear Andrew, thank you for your answer. Do you know if there is a positive or negative answer to the exact highlighted question? Let's suppose we *know* that $T$ exists and is given by the relative $\operatorname{Spec}$ as defined in the question. You said that $$T(C)=Hom_K(\operatorname{Spec}(C[t]/t^2),X)=Hom_K(\operatorname{Spec}(C)\times_{K}\operatorname{Spec}(K[t]/t^2),X)$$ which I understand now. The *hom-sheaf* from the question is $Hom_K(-\times_K\operatorname{Spec}(K[t]/t^2),X):Schemes/K^{op}\to Sets$ and hence a positive answer seems not absurd, does it?

Comment: Dear @RonaldBernard, I am confused by the definition of $S.$ The $\mathcal{Hom}$ sheaf takes as inputs sheaves on $X,$ so we have expressions like $V\mapsto\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal F|_V,\mathcal G|_V).$ How do you view $\operatorname{Spec}(K[t]/t^2)$ and $X$ as sheaves?

Comment: Dear @Andrew, I meant the $\mathcal{H}om$ sheaf basechanged to the big topos: The two objects in question are sheaves $Schemes/K^{op}\to Sets$ for the Zariski topology. By definition $$S(-):=Hom_K(-\times_K \operatorname{Spec}(K[t]/t^2),X)$$. Hence my question is if there is an isomorphism between $S(-)$ and $Hom_K(-,T)$.

Comment: Dear @Ronald, I was confused by the use of calligraphic script for the "Hom" in the question. But yes, the construction of "T" using relative spec does give the correct scheme, so that its functor of points is isomorphic to the $S$ in your comments.